# Task and Activity stack : what is difference between both.

Tags: android

I followed some tutorials but got confused with "Activity stack" and "Task".

- Because both starts when a new activity is created.
- Activity stack keeps a navigation history of activities, and Task is a sequence of activities.

Is this is only difference that Activity stack made up of one or more task(S)?

Give some example please.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack in the android doc, and the developer blog at https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/tasks-and-the-back-stack-dbb7c3b0f6d4

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Activities and Tasks**

As noted earlier, one `Activity` can start another, including one defined in a different `Application`. Suppose, for example, that you'd like to let users display a street map of some location. There's already an activity that can do that, so all your activity needs to do is put together an `Intent` object with the required information and pass it to `startActivity()`. The map viewer will display the map. When the user hits the **BACK key**, your activity will reappear on screen.

To the user, it will seem as if the map viewer is part of the same application as your activity, even though it's defined in another application and runs in that application's process. **Android maintains this user experience by keeping both activities in the same task. Simply put, a task is what the user experiences as an "application".** It's a group of related activities, arranged in a stack.

Task = Application = Set of activities.

Comment: Thank you pedr0. But I am asking about "activity stack" and "Tasks".

Comment: set of activity are organized in a stack! a Task is only an application!

Comment: The activities are arranged in a stack (the back stack), in the order in which each activity is opened.

Comment: Task = Application isn't true task could = application, but application could = set of tasks for example by using lanuchMode="singleTask" in AndroidManifest.xml so Application = set of tasks, task = set of activities.

Comment: This answer could be improved, because the difference between `Task` and `Activity task` isn't even mentioned.

Comment: We can see the tasks in [the Recents screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents)

Answer (score 2):

A task is not an application. The former is a set of Activities that the user has visited, while the latter is a collection of Android components (Activities, Services, ContentProviders and BroadcastReceivers) that are declared in an application's manifest.

The Activities of a given task can come from other applications as well as the current application. Taken together, these Activities represent the "path" that a user has taken to accomplish some objective.  They are stored in the task's back stack in LIFO order; each task has its own back stack.

Task management, either through  attributes such as launchMode, taskAffinity, etc, and/or intent flags, allows us to control the relationship between tasks and Activities.

For more information, please see: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack